# How to test namedNativeQuery with Mockito and Junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito to test a namedNativeQuery, I mocked the query and result but Got the error :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: La fonction "TARIFVENTEPUBLICCOUR_PRODENAGC" na pas été trouvée
Function {0} not found; SQL statement:
  ? = call BRAVO_REFERENCEMENT_PRODUIT.TARIFVENTEPUBLICCOUR_PRODENAGC(?, ?)
```

Here is My code, I found that I should create the function in a h2 sql but not sure of this solution and didn't find an example of how to create it

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "spring.profiles.active=test",
})
@Transactional
@Sql({"../student-data.sql"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class StudentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository StudentRepository;

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Mock
    private Query query;

    private Student student = new Student();

    @Test
    public void givenIdContratCadreList_thenReturn_Student() {

      when(entityManager.createNamedQuery("getStudent")).thenReturn(query);
      when(query.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(student);

      Student returnedResponse = this.studentRepository.getStudent(12L, 12L);
      Assert.assertNotNull(returnedResponse);

    }
```

Comment: It is always adviced to use Mockito.anyString() instead of the value itself, in case of "getStudent". In other words, please try replacing "getStudent" by Mockito.anyString()

Comment: Your test with mocks isn't really testing anything, you are only testing the mocking framework.

Comment: There does not seem to be a relation between your mocks and the `StudentRepository`. You have to inject you mocks into your class under test. Anyway if you want to test a layer which includes database interaction you should look into IntegrationTests against a real database instead.